# Memory leak with Picasso and FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, memory-leaks, android-viewpager, picasso

I have a fragment with a list of some advertisements(adv). When i click on particular adv i .add() a fragment with description of this adv - the viewpager with list of some pics and some text.

So if i click about 30 advs i have a memory leak. 
Looks like the leak caused by a viewpager (FragmentStatePagerAdapter) with the pics loaded from internet with the help of Picasso. 
So is there a way to clear the memory?
thanks

Answer (score 3):

> So is there a way to clear the memory?

Picasso.with(context).cache.clear();